# Чтение из нескольких потоков C#

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Имеется многопоточный http-сервер, который принимает запросы API. Соответственно каждый запрос в отдельном потоке. Из этих потоков идет обращение к статическому классу:

```
public static class Collector
{
    private static Dictionary<string, Directions> Inbox = new Dictionary<string, Directions>();

    public static void Load(Packages.Mango.Call pkg)
    {
        if (pkg.CallState != "Disconnected")
        {
            if (Inbox.ContainsKey(pkg.EntryId))
            {
                Inbox[pkg.EntryId].Update(pkg);

                if (Inbox[pkg.EntryId].Count == 0)
                {
                    Inbox.Remove(pkg.EntryId);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Inbox.Add(pkg.EntryId, new Directions(pkg));
            }   
        }
        else if (Inbox.ContainsKey(pkg.EntryId)) // Disconnected
        {
            Inbox.Remove(pkg.EntryId);
        }
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что когда приходит сразу 2 одинаковых запроса, с одинаковым pkg.EntryId, то строка

```
Inbox.Add(pkg.EntryId, new Directions(pkg));
```

выполняется 2 раза. Как этого избежать? Использовать события или внедрять FIFO для обработки пакетов?

Comment: а данные, собранные в Inbox, будут обрабатываться?

Comment: Обрабатываться не будут! Только добавление и удаление.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Варианты решения:

1. Продолжать использовать `Dictionary`. Но тогда *каждое* обращение
   должно быть обернуто в `lock`.
2. Использовать `ConcurrentDictionary`. Но нужно помнить о том, что он
   дает потокобезопасную проверку/добавление/удаление *только* по
   отдельности. Т.е. ваш сценарий "проверить, есть ли ключ, если ключа нет,
   то добавить" *все еще* нуждается в `lock`. Подробнее можно почитать в статье [Dictionary + Locking versus ConcurrentDictionary](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/548406/Dictionary-plus-Locking-versus-ConcurrentDictionar).

Еще совет: вместо связки `ContainsKey`+получение значение лучше использовать `TryGetValue`.

Comment: В ситуации, описанной в вопросе (проверка + добавление) по идее правильно сработает только первый вариант.

Comment: @VladD мм, `ConcurrectDictionary`+`lock` тоже ведь сработает, разве нет? Другое дело, что если больше нет никаких "простых" обращений в словарю, то смысла в `ConcurrentDictionary` тут и нет.

Comment: Угу, вроде бы `ConcurrentDictionary` не имеет особого смысла в присутствии `lock`'а. Я бы по идее либо пользовался `lock`'ом всё время, либо не пользовался, иначе есть хороший шанс получить «тонкие», трудновоспроизводимые ошибки (например, если `lock` используется непоследовательно, и в некоторых случаях прочитанное без `lock`'а значение используется позже).

Answer (score 0):

Для начала, откройте для себя класс [`ConcurrentDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx). Большую часть проблем этот класс сможет взять на себя.

Если же этого класса недостаточно - то традиционным решением являются мониторы и ключевое слово [`lock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/c5kehkcz.aspx)

Если же понадобится поднять производительность - то надо делать очереди запросов, совмещая их с асинхронным программированием.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx), но у него есть некоторые [особенности](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9872696/5673266).

Если несколько потоков добавляют/меняют значения в словаре, то можно использовать специальный класс [ReaderWriterLockSlim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx) для управления доступом, примерно так

```
private ReaderWriterLockSlim cacheLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
private Dictionary<int, string> innerCache = new Dictionary<int, string>();

public void AddOrUpdate(int key, string value) {
    cacheLock.EnterUpgradeableReadLock();
    try {
        string result = null;
        if (innerCache.TryGetValue(key, out result)) {
            if (result == value) return;
            else {
                cacheLock.EnterWriteLock();
                try { innerCache[key] = value; } 
                finally { cacheLock.ExitWriteLock(); }
                return;
            }
        } else {
            cacheLock.EnterWriteLock();
            try { innerCache.Add(key, value); } 
            finally { cacheLock.ExitWriteLock(); }
            return;
        }
    }
    finally { cacheLock.ExitUpgradeableReadLock(); }
}    

public void Delete(int key) {
    cacheLock.EnterWriteLock();
    try { innerCache.Remove(key); }
    finally { cacheLock.ExitWriteLock();}
}

public string Read(int key) {
    cacheLock.EnterReadLock();
    try { return innerCache[key]; }
    finally { cacheLock.ExitReadLock(); }
}
```

---

См. [Dictionary + Locking versus ConcurrentDictionary](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/548406/Dictionary-plus-Locking-versus-ConcurrentDictionar) -- Paulo Zemek, Engineer Microsoft Corp.